# What do Plummeting into an abyss & have a good cry mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

```
1. Plummeting into an abyss 

I’m guessing it may have another meaning here than what I found.

When I looked up in the dictionary, I got the following definition :

Plummeting - to fall suddenly and quickly from a high level or position

abyss - a very deep wide space or hole that seems to have no bottom
```

> 2. Have a good cry.
>
> I guess it means Eric likes to think about the old time with his dad. Am I close?
>
> **Here's the only one research I found:**
>
> http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/cry_2
>
> **[SINGULAR] a period of time when you have tears coming from your eyes,
>   especially because you are sad have a (good) cry: She went to the
>   toilet and had a good cry.**

```
Context: Stosh is Eric's cousin who is just moving in Eric's house. 
Eric's father just passed away.
```

**[Stosh's just woken up and he sees Eric is standing next to his bed.]**

> Stosh: (grumbles) Oh, God!
>
> Eric: Hey, sleepyhead.(chuckles)
>
> Stosh: (groans) How long you been staring at me?
>
> Eric: Mm, about an hour.(groans) Hey, what were you dreaming about?
>
> Stosh: ***Plummeting into an abyss***. Same as usual.
>
> Eric: I'm sorry. I'm just.. I'm used to coming in here to wake up Pop
>   every morning. You know? He'd be laying right there, right where you
>   are, scratching all over 'cause of his skin thing. (chuckles) I'd tell
>   him, "Pop, don't scratch, you know? You got to let that scab over. "
>   But guess what, he'd keep digging.
>
> Stoch: You know what, ***you have a good cry***. I'm gonna go boil
>   myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "abyss" is a very deep hole or pit. So "falling into an abyss" literally means falling down a very deep hole. Figuratively, then, it can mean getting into some problem that you can't get out of. The idea of falling and falling and never reaching the bottom can also be frightening, so the phrase can be used to mean something scary.

"Have a good cry" means to spend time crying. It's usually used to describe someone who has just had some very bad or sad experience, and goes off by herself (usually but not always used in reference to a woman) somewhere to just sit and cry about it and get the bad feelings out of her system. Like, "When my boyfriend dumped me, I went home and had a good cry."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the origin of this superstition/trope or whatever you want to call it, but dreaming of falling is associated with doom and a premonition of dying.  Also, the word *abyss* can be sometimes associated to the idea of Hell and rejection/condemnation.

"Have a good cry" is advice sometimes given to grieving people, the idea that "letting it all out" and letting the sadness take its course is better than keeping it "bottled up."

Comment: The book of Revelation in the Bible talks about the "Abyss" as a place were demons are imprisoned and where an army of strange creatures comes from to torment evil people at the end of the age. Whether it's another name for Hell or is a place associated with Hell or just what is getting into theological questions that are surely out of the scope of this forum. Just a couple of months ago I published a book that discusses the Abyss and other interesting places mentioned in the Bible, but I will with great restraint refrain from trying to plug my book here. :-)

Comment: @ultrasawblade Thanks for your answers!! I really appreciate your help!